# Is there anyway to bold certain regions of imagesc in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, border

The following matrix was derived from imagesc(rand(10,10)) as a pure example. [image]

I was wondering if there was a way in MATLAB to give a bold black border to certain elements? I did a poor example in MS paint just to get the point across. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative that is better in my view, is to use `patch`, for example:

```
imagesc(rand(10,10)), hold on

vert = 0.5+[0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1]; % x and y vertex coordinates
fac = [1 2 3 4];              % vertices to connect to make square

patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceColor','none','LineWidth',2)

vert2 = 0.5+[5 6; 5 8; 9 8; 9 5; 7 5; 7 6]; % x and y vertex coordinates
fac2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 ];  % vertices to connect to make the other closed polygon

patch('Faces',fac2,'Vertices',vert2,'FaceColor','none','LineWidth',2)
```

[image]

Note that the reason I added 0.5 to the vertex coordinates is because in `imagesc` the bins are centered around integer values, ans so the bin edges are on 0.5 values.

Comment: Thank you, very easily implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `plot` to plot lines wherever you want.

```
imagesc(rand(10,10)), hold on
plot([1.5,1.5],[0,10],'black','LineWidth',3)
```

and then define your bounding boxes the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hadn't thought about using hold on.