# Printing "snake" plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I need print plot like this:

[image: plot]

```
function draw123(n)
x=1:n;
y=zeros(1,n); 
l=1;
x=[x,n]; y=[y,l];
x=[x,4,3,2]; y=[y,1,1,1]; % from this moment rest of code(with this line) work correctly only for n==6
x=[x,2]; y=[y,2];
x=[x,3,4,5]; y=[y,2,2,2];
plot(x,y)
```

My code works only for n==6 but it should work for every other n(1,2,...,99,100)

Comment: there's no `n` in your code...

Comment: look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595856/is-there-anyway-to-bold-certain-regions-of-imagesc-in-matlab/31597305#31597305

Comment: @whrrgarbl sorry this should be: x=1:n and y=zeros(1,n)

Comment: Can you edit that into your question? The way you're using `n` is pretty important to writing a proper answer.

Comment: Also, include the error message you are getting - I am getting an error just running your code as written, with `x=1:6; y=zeroes(1,6)` ("vectors must be the same length").

Comment: @whrrgarbl I just paste my new code, now everything should be fine

Comment: Hm, I just tried running that and it didn't give me any errors.. what problem are you seeing?

Comment: @whrrgarbl I just explained it here http://s13.postimg.org/qeh3gn2w7/1313.png

Comment: It seems the values of the snake is either 0 or hardcoded. You have to write a formula for n. For the ones still having trouble with the IQ test, I think I solved it. It seems the first line have length n. Then for each step up the line gets shortened by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a simple task combinatorically, but this should work. You need to create a formula which gives the correct point every time. To make it a bit simpler I created two variables `lineLength` and `direction` which calcualte how long the next line must be and if it have positive or negative direction. The vertical points are alternated between same as previous and same as previous plus one. Further, I need to access the previous element in the loop, so I set the first two before the loop. I also set the last value after the loop since it does not behave like the other values.

```
function draw123(n)
y(2*n+1,1) = 0;
x = y;
x(2) = n;

for k = 3:2:2*n-1
    x(k) = x(k-1);
    lineLength = (n-(k-1)/2);
    direction = (-1)^((k-1)/2); % +1 or -1
    x(k+1) = lineLength * direction + x(k-1);
    y(k) = y(k-1)+1;
    y(k+1) = y(k);
end

x(end) = x(end-1);
y(end) = y(end-1)+1;

plot(x,y,'r');
```